# Turn Pandas Dataframe into a dictionary of Objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Need to group rows by the File_Number which will act as the dictionaries key, and have the Action_ID and Action_Note as an object.

**DataFrame**

```
**File_Number**   **Action_ID**    **Action_Note**
       0              12          Call Josh
       1              15          Text Emily
       1              16          Email Guy
       2              19          Visit Hannah
       2              20          Call Ryan
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
0: [Action_ID: 12, Action_Note: Call Josh ],
1: [Action_ID: 15, Action_Note: Text Emily], [Action_ID: 16, Action_Note: Email Guy],
2: [Action_ID: 19, Action_Note: Visit Hannah], [Action_ID: 20, Action_Note: Call Ryan],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `to_dict` twice:

```
(df.drop(['File_Number'], axis=1)
   .groupby(df['File_Number']).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records'))
   .to_dict()
)
```

Output:

```
{0: [{'Action_ID': 12, 'Action_Note': 'Call Josh'}],
 1: [{'Action_ID': 15, 'Action_Note': 'Text Emily'},
  {'Action_ID': 16, 'Action_Note': 'Email Guy'}],
 2: [{'Action_ID': 19, 'Action_Note': 'Visit Hannah'},
  {'Action_ID': 20, 'Action_Note': 'Call Ryan'}]}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!